# Meaning of “gopher” as a job?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

Would you please explain to me what does “gopher” mean as a job? The dictionary says it means someone who run errands but I cannot understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanBron et al.: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe **gofer** is the correct word  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gofer) Slang (orig. and chiefly N. Amer.).

> an employee whose duties include running errands

As a **gofer** your job might include delivering packages, 'fetching' lunch, and other odd jobs.  Personal chores are not out of bounds. The word describes anyone whose job is as a "guy (or gal) Friday" The word was coined in the 1950s, from the sense of "go for," and echoing the word **gopher**.  In professional bicycle racing, the 'domestiques'(aka housekeepers) in the races use themselves up doing the hard pulls, going back for water and even sacrificing their bicycles the the 'leader' when necessary.

Here are a couple of recent uses of gofer:

> Mr. Lee was initially paid $8 a week as an office gofer. New York
>   Times Nov 11, 2018

and

> “I was a gofer for anything the players wanted,” he said. Washington
>   Times Oct 25, 2016

An apt word, as real gophers work on and below the ground.